# Why Finch using EndPoint to represent Router, Request Parameter and Request Body

Tags: web-services, scala, finagle, finch

In finch, we can define router, request parameters, request body like this.

```
  case class Test(name: String, age: Int)

  val router: Endpoint[Test] = post("hello") { Ok(Test("name", 30)) }
  val requestBody: Endpoint[Test] = body.as[Test]
  val requestParameters: Endpoint[Test] = Endpoint.derive[Test].fromParams
```

The benefit is that we can compose EndPoint together. For example, I can define:

The request path is **hello** and **Parameter** should have **name** and **age**. (`router :: requestParameters`)

However, I can still run an **invalid** endpoint which doesnt include any **request path** successfully (There is actually no compilation error)

```
Await.ready(Http.serve(":3000", requestParameters.toService))
```

The result is returning 404 not found page. Even though I expect that the error should report earlier like compilation error. I wonder that is this a design drawback or it is actually finch trying to fix ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks a lot for asking this!

Let me give you some insight on how Finch's endpoints work. If you speak category theory, an `Endpoint` is an `Applicative` embedding `StateT` represented as something close to `Input => Option[(Input, A)]`.

Simply speaking, an endpoint takes an `Input` that wraps an HTTP request and also captures the *current path* (eg: `/foo/bar/baz`). When endpoint is applied on to a given request and either *matches* it (returning `Some`) or *falls over* (returning `None`). When matched, it changes the state of the `Input`, usually removing the first path segment from it (eg: removing `foo` from `/foo/bar/baz`) so the next endpoint is the chain can work with a new `Input` (and new path).

Once endpoint is matched, Finch checks if there is something else left in the `Input` that wasn't matched. If something is left, the match considered unsuccessful and your service returns 404.

```
scala> val e = "foo" :: "bar"
e: io.finch.Endpoint[shapeless.HNil] = foo/bar

scala> e(Input(Request("/foo/bar/baz"))).get._1.path
res1: Seq[String] = List(baz)
```

When it comes to endpoints matching/extracting query-string params, no path segments are being touched there and the state is passed to the next endpoint unchanged. So when an endpoint `param("foo")` is applied, the path is not affected. That simply means, the only way to *serve* a query-string endpoint (note: an endpoint that only extract query-string params) is to send it a request with empty path `/`.

```
scala> val s = param("foo").toService
s: com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response] = <function1>

scala> s(Request("/", "foo" -> "bar")).get
res4: com.twitter.finagle.http.Response = Response("HTTP/1.1 Status(200)")

scala> s(Request("/bar", "foo" -> "bar")).get
res5: com.twitter.finagle.http.Response = Response("HTTP/1.1 Status(404)")
```